# How does cython improve performance of pure python code

Tags: python, cython

Here is the code:

```
## x.py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

for i in range(9999):
    for j in range(1, 9999):           
        pass

## x1.pyx
#!/usr/bin/env python3

# cdef double total = 0.0
# cdef int i, j
for i in range(9999):
    for j in range(1, 9999):          
        pass

## setup.py 

from distutils.core import setup
from Cython.Build import cythonize

setup(
    ext_modules = cythonize("x1.pyx")
)
```

In shell:

```
➜  /tmp  python3 setup.py build_ext --inplace
➜  /tmp  time python3 -c "import x1"
python3 -c "import x1"  2.86s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 2.875 total
➜  /tmp  time ./x.py
./x.py  4.94s user 0.01s system 99% cpu 4.961 total
```

It looks like cython brings a 2x performance boost even without touching static typing, how does it do this? Does this mean it will universally improve performance of **pure** python code?

Answer (score 4):

Cython translates Python code into actual C, so it can run at a level very close to native code. So any drawback from the dynamic Python interpreter you have with normal Python code is gone. This allows Cython code to be a lot faster, especially for such tasks as your example shows which is purely utilizing the CPU alone.